# A new device showed up on facetime which I don't own

Tags: macbook-pro

I got a notification saying a MacBook Pro is using facetime with my Apple ID, but I don't have a MacBook Pro. How do I verify what device this is and where it is coming from? Should I be concerned about this?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of those notifications is to alert you to the possibility of unauthorized usage on your Apple ID. Obviously, I get them any time I restore a computer, load up a new device, or just sign out of Facetime (or Messages) and back in, but for me it makes sense as I can relate it to a particular event.

Since you do not have a MacBook Pro, you certainly have reason to be suspicious. An Apple ID can expose a large amount of information to a nefarious user.

If I were you I would *[reset my Apple ID password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201355)* and *[enable 2-step authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152)*.